# Flutter: How to try catch process after few seconds

Tags: android, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I Have function like below:

```
  Future getArticles() async {
    try {
      _loadingArticleController.sink.add(true);
      Response response;
      var dio = ApiProvider.dio();

      response = await dio.get("/article/get-random-lang?category=1&lang=${translations.currentLanguage}");
      var data = response.data['data'];
      print(data);
      articleList.clear();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          model = articleFromJson(json.encode(data[i]));
          articleList.add(model);
        }

        // sink to the stream
        _articlesController.sink.add(articleList);
        _loadingArticleController.sink.add(false);
        await Storage.storeArticles(data);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new DioError(
          response: Response(
            statusCode: response.data['status'], 
            data: {
              'message': response.data['message']
            }
          )
        );
      }
    }
    on DioError catch (e) {
      var articles = await Storage.getArticles();
      if (articles.length > 0) {
        articleList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
          Article model = await compute(articleFromJson, json.encode(articles[i]));
          articleList.add(model);
        }
        _articlesController.sink.add(articleList);
      } else {
        _articlesController.sink.add([]);
      }
      _loadingArticleController.sink.add(false);

      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
      if (e.response != null) {
        print(e.response);
        print(e.response.headers);
        print(e.response.request);
        
      } else {
        // Something happen
        print(e);
      }
    } 
  }
```

In above function i have an anticipation, if function become error then take data from storage. However, I dont know how to using try catch **if timeout occurs**, let's says for 10 seconds.

any idea?

Thank You In Advance

Comment: explain more what are you taking about?

Comment: @Harsh0021 i mean, as default in my function i want to get data from API/web but if it taking too long i want to get data from local/file

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, you could create a timer which is going to be 10 seconds and put the function inside your try block. Now if the 10 seconds are done and you want your function to be interrupted, you can cancel it by just return noting in the function and call `cancelTimer` to break it.

```
Timer _timer;
  _startTimer() {
    _cancelTimer();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      _cancelTimer();
    });
  }

  _cancelTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Marcel Thank you, however is this possible to place this logic in widget / UI ?

Comment: Hi, well you could create a MaterialButton for canceling and in the onpressed function you can put the _canceltimer(). In the _startTimer() you would then add your get articles code. Then your able to interrupt it with the button or after 10 sec